# Create Relational database to store questions and its options

Tags: database-design

I want to create database to store questions and its options with correct answer. How should I design the database so that I will get all questions with it's correct answer and options.

```
I have created 2 tables
1.Questions(tablename):
   Columns are:
   1.QuestionID uniqueidentifier(PK)
   2.QuestionText nvarchar(500)
   3.IsActiveQuestion bit
   4.CorrectAnswerID uniqueidentifier(FK)
   5.UploadedBy uniqueidentifier(FK)

2.AnswerDetails(tablename):
   Columns are:
   1.AnswerID uniqueidentifier(PK)
   2.QuestionId uniqueidentifier(FK)
   3.Answertext nvarchar(200)
   4.IsCorrectAnswer bit

I want 
1. Question
2. It's options(Answers)
3. CorrectAnswer
4. IsActive

as a output
```

.

Comment: Your design for the required need looks correct to me (leaving the decision for size of columns to you). Are you rather looking for the query? If so, I think you should ask that in your post as it does not look clear.

Comment: I am not looking for query. I just want to clear that this design of tables is correct or not? I have to store MCQ questions in database.

Comment: Looks correct to me. You should also make the proper columns NOT NULL. Eg. QuestionId in your AnswerDetail table should be a NOT NULL column as each answer must be of a particular question. But if you have a requirement of one answer can be answer to multiple questions, then you have to design it differently.